# Virial theorem and gravity simulation?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, computational-physics, simulations, virial-theorem

I've been trying to build a gravitational simulation using a newtonian law of gravitation and have just been going over what the initial conditions should be. Then I remembered the virial theorem and purely gravitationally bound systems in which,

$$ 0 = 2K_{tot} + U_{tot} =  \sum_i m_{i} |\vec{v}_{i}|^{2} -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \ne j} \frac{Gm_{i}m_{j}}{|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_{j}|}. $$

Could I then use this to find out the initial positions and initial velocities for a realistic gravitating system?

Comment: Justin Orosz, I lightly edited your question. If you're unhappy with it, please revert.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri, thank you. Now you get a cookie.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri, did you add the half because summing over n-particles with $i \ne j$ would lead to counting twice over with the potentials?

Comment: It sums over ij and ji

Comment: The viral theorem basically defines which areas are gravitationally unstable. In astrophysics one measures kinetic energy to judge wether a molecule cloud of a(n assumed mass) is unstable. Yet it does not talk about distribution in the volume (however you can reduce scale to judge fragmentation)

Comment: Justin Orosz, I didn't edit the equation.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri, Oh.